# ProgressBar Start at 1 Instead of 0

Tags: python, progress-bar, progress

I have a progress bar that looks like this:

```
employees = ["1G8764897", "1J6734897", "1J5292897"]
jobs = len(employees)
print

widgets = ['Processed: ', Counter(), ' of ', str(len(employees)),  ' profiles (', Timer(), ')']
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets)
for i in pbar((i for i in employees)):
    time.sleep(.01)
    fetchdata(i)
print "done"
```

But when it runs, it finishes with "2 out of 3 completed".
I would like it to say 3 out of 3 completed, and start counting at 1 instead of 0. I cant figure out how to do this for the life of me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would this work?  `widgets = ['Processed: ', (Counter()+1), ' of ', ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, no, throws this error:

`widgets = ['Processed: ', (Counter()+1), ' of ', str(len(employees)),  ' profiles (', Timer(), ')']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Counter' and 'int'`